# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EF3 when crawling 2008 R2 static HTML site

Tags: search, crawling

All I want to do is index a static HTML site.  Am I the first person to ever do this with SharePoint?

I was having the problem described here:
[Why can't I crawl bog-standard HTML internet sites?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13799/why-cant-i-crawl-bog-standard-html-internet-sites)

Apparently this issues is addressed in the August 2010 Cumulative Update, which is included in SP1, which I installed today.

I eagerly tried out the search... and I seem to have swapped one error code for another.

In the crawl log I get:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EF3

In the Windows Log I get:
    The start address http://asia-pacific.undp.org cannot be crawled.

```
Context: Application 'Search_Service_Application_Dev', Catalog 'Portal_Content'

Details:
The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation   (0x80072ef3)
```

Googling brings up some results from SP2003, but that's about it.  Anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mystery solved.  Earlier I'd set up a crawl rule to try to avoid having the index spider log into an anonymous access site.  It was trying to give a certificate.  When I removed the rule the site indexed OK.